# Enforce an entity to only exist as a parent OR child in a relationship table

Tags: database-design

Edit: Apologies, I have now reworded my question as my colleague and I were in a rush when it was initially written and I noticed it was badly phrased.

I have a contact table as follows:

**Contact**

Contact id

some more fields

A contact must either be a child or a parent.  I have a parent child relationship table:

**Parent Children**
id

Parent id

Child id

You cannot have a tree depth of greater than one within this table (I already know how to do this bit).  The part I am unsure about is that I want to make sure when adding to the 'parent children' table that parents and children cannot be added to the wrong column - ie a parent can only go to the parent column, and a child can only go to the child column.

Contacts are currently defined to be a parent or a child with a flag in the contact table which I do not think is the best system.  This is because it is possible for a parent to have no children, or child to have no parents hence no presence of the contact in 'Parent Children'

So in summary I want to store contacts which must be either a parent or child.  They do not have be part of any relationship, but if they are they will be stored as parent child relationships which can only have a depth one (enforcing the tree depth is the part I currently know how to do), and I want to make sure a parent contact can only be a parent in the relationship table, and a child contact can only be a child in the relationship table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simplify things (if you have a maximum depth of 1):

Table People

```
id | parent_id | name
```

Table Contact

```
id | people_id
```

How it works:

A person out of the people table is a parent if `parent_id IS NULL`.

Select all children:

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE parent_id IS NOT NULL
```

Select all parents:

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE parent_id IS NULL
```

Select all parent contacts:

```
SELECT * FROM contacts
   INNER JOIN people ON people.id = contacts.people_id 
WHERE
   people.parent_id IS NULL
```

Select all child contacts:

```
SELECT * FROM contacts
   INNER JOIN people ON people.id = contacts.people_id 
WHERE
   people.parent_id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a good solution but I neglected to mention that you can have a child contact with no parents.  Any other help appreciated, please see my edit as I have tried to phrase my question better.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I have got your question but If you need a parent child relationship where the record is not "rich" you could keep everything in one table even to improve the performance

```
Contact
-IdContact
-IdParentContact  (will be an IdContact)
-OtherFields
```

all the root will have ParentContact at NULL

Do am I missing something?